# Syntax error in create table query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

I cant get this syntax error.

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`id`) ENGINE=MyISAM)' at line 15

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `destination_cdr` (
 `id` BIGINT( 20 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `calldate` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
 `source` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
 `destination` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
 `account_code` VARCHAR( 30 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `pincode` VARCHAR( 45 ) NOT NULL ,
 `duration_call` BIGINT( 20 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `duration_talk` BIGINT( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
 `disposition` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `clid` VARCHAR( 80 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `cdr_id` BIGINT( 20 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `vxcdr_id` BIGINT( 20 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `provider` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )) ENGINE = MYISAM
;
```

Comment: First question here, please read what to do [when you get answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a commma between provider and primary Key:

```
 `provider` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0', PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing comma before primary key clause.

```
   `provider` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0', PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ))
```

Answer (score -1):

Error
SQL query:

--

### -- Database: `wadud`

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `destination`

```
CREATE TABLE destination (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  country varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  photo text NOT NULL,
  tours varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1050 - Table 'destination' already exists